# Alternative for Celery

Tags: python

I setup a system, that, with the help of `RabbitMQ`, `Python` and `Celery` distributes tasks to several machines and returns a result.

Unfortunately I haven't seen coming that `Celery` doesn't work on Windows and it is very buggy. So I am trying to find an alternative Queue System which can fulfill the following requirements below. Can anyone share some experiences?

```
> Tasks take between 5 and 50 minutes
> Tasks are CPU-bound (99% CPU load)
> Tasks are consumed/executed only once at a time per worker (never in parallel)
> Tasks can be cancelled from the 'sender' side
> Tasks can return a result to its caller
> Supports RabbitMQ
> Has Python bindings
```